# Parser java interface to html interface

Tags: java, html

I wish to create a app that translates input java code into HTML,i have a parser for create frame, button, textfield etc.
all of component of package java AWT Have been rewritten .
I need to implements a method for create a tag html dialog and insert  any component

```
public static void addmenu(ArrayList<pMenu> bar){

        tag_div = doc.createElement("div");
        body.appendChild(tag_div);
        tag_div.setAttribute("id", "myNav");
        tag_div.setAttribute("class", "frame overlay");


        Element a = doc.createElement("a");
        a.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("x"));
        tag_div.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");
        a.setAttribute("class", "closebtn");
        a.setAttribute("onclick", "closeNav()");


        span_menu = doc.createElement("span");
        span_menu.setAttribute("class", "overlay-content");

        tag_div.appendChild(span_menu);

        /

        parse_menu(bar);

        /*
            Element viewport = doc.createElement("META");
            viewport.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
            viewport.setAttribute("content", "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi");
            head.appendChild(viewport);

            body = doc.createElement("BODY");
            body.setAttribute("onhashchange", "updateFooter();");
            body.setAttribute("onload", "defaultFrame();");
            rootElement.appendChild(body);
        */

}


public static void parse_menu(ArrayList<pMenu> bar){
    int i;


    Element ul = doc.createElement("ul"); 
    span_menu.appendChild(ul);
    for(i=0;i<bar.size();i++){

            Element li = doc.createElement("li"); 
            ul.appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("- " + bar.get(i).getName()  + ": "));
            li.setAttribute("onclick", "insert_menu(this)");
            li.setAttribute("class", "colorMenu");
            li.setAttribute("style", "color: #ecf503;");
            //System.out.println(); 
            if(bar.get(i).has_item())
                parse_menu_item(li, bar.get(i).getArray_menu());


    }

}



private static void parse_menu_item(Element tag_li, ArrayList<pMenuItem> pmenui){
    int i;

    Element ul = doc.createElement("ul"); 
    tag_li.appendChild(ul);
    ul.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
    for(i=0;i<pmenui.size();i++){

            Element li = doc.createElement("li"); 
            ul.appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(pmenui.get(i).getName()) ); 
            li.setAttribute("id", pmenui.get(i).getName() );    
            li.setAttribute("onclick", "app.fire(id)");
            li.setAttribute("class", "subnav");
            if(pmenui.get(i).has_item())
                parse_menu_item(li, pmenui.get(i).getArray_menu());



    }
    //System.out.println("</ul>"); 
}


public static void parse(pComponent c){

    if(c instanceof pFrame){
        for(pComponent component : ((pFrame) c).getComponents()) //tutti i pComponent del pFrame
            parse(component);
    } else if(c instanceof pPanel){ //AGGIUNGO I PANNELLI, con all'interno i pComponent
        for(pComponent component : ((pPanel) c).getComponents())
            parse(component);
    }else if(c instanceof pDialog){ 
        System.out.println(c.getClass().getName());
        c.create();
        for(pComponent component : ((pDialog) c).getComponents()){
            parse(component);
        }
    }else{

        if((c instanceof pMenuBar)||(c instanceof pMenuItem)||(c instanceof pMenu)){
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("creating: "+c.getName());
        System.out.println("parent: " +c.getRoot().getName()+"  "+ c.getRoot().getClass().getName());

        c.create(); //chiamo il metodo create di ogni pComponent dell'applicazione. 
    }
}



public static void createPage(String title, Set<Set<String>> partition){
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("HTML");
        head = doc.createElement("HEAD");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);
        addCss("css/index.css");
        addCss("css/ionic.css");
        addCss("css/ionicons.min.css");
        addCss("css/menu/menulaterale.css");


        rootElement.appendChild(head);

        Element viewport = doc.createElement("META");
        viewport.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
        viewport.setAttribute("content", "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi");
        head.appendChild(viewport);


        Element title1 = doc.createElement("TITLE");
        title1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(title));
        head.appendChild(title1);

        body = doc.createElement("BODY");
        body.setAttribute("onhashchange", "updateFooter();");
        body.setAttribute("onload", "defaultFrame();");
        rootElement.appendChild(body);
        _partition = partition;

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Element addFrame(String title){
    Element frame = doc.createElement("DIV");
    frame.setAttribute("id", title);
    frame.setAttribute("class", "frame");

    Element div_menu = doc.createElement("div");
    frame.appendChild(div_menu);
    div_menu.setAttribute("class", "scritta_menu");
    div_menu.setAttribute("onclick", "openNav()");
    div_menu.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("||| MENU"));
    return frame;
}



//AGGIUNGO L'HEADER DELLA BARRA - RUBRICA - DOVE DOVREBBE ANDARE IL MENU
public static void addHeader(String title){
    /*
    SAMPLE IONIC CODE
    <div id="title" class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Java AWT Calc</h1>
    </div>
    */
    Element header = doc.createElement("DIV");
    header.setAttribute("id", "title");
    header.setAttribute("class", "bar bar-header bar-positive");

    Element h1 = doc.createElement("H1");
    h1.setAttribute("class", "title");

    h1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(title));
    header.appendChild(h1);
    body.appendChild(header);
}

private static void addFooter(){
    Element footer = doc.createElement("DIV");
    Element framesBullets = doc.createElement("DIV");
    Element buttonLeft = doc.createElement("BUTTON");
    Element buttonRight = doc.createElement("BUTTON");
    footer.setAttribute("id", "footer");
    buttonLeft.setAttribute("id","buttonLeft");
    buttonRight.setAttribute("id","buttonRight");
    framesBullets.setAttribute("id", "framesBullets");
    framesBullets.setAttribute("class", "title" );
    footer.setAttribute("class", "bar bar-positive bar-footer");
    buttonLeft.setAttribute("class", "hide button button-clear icon-left ion-android-arrow-dropleft-circle");
    buttonRight.setAttribute("class", "hide button button-clear icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle");
    footer.appendChild(buttonLeft);
    footer.appendChild(framesBullets);
    footer.appendChild(buttonRight);
    body.appendChild(footer);
}

private static void addScript(String path){
    Element script= doc.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", path);
    body.appendChild(script);
}

private static void addCss(String path){
    Element css = doc.createElement("LINK");
    css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    css.setAttribute("href", path);
    head.appendChild(css);

}

public static void addButton(String name, Element root){
    Element button = doc.createElement("BUTTON");
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("class", "button");
    button.setAttribute("id", name);
    button.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(name));
    button.setAttribute("onClick", buttonEvent);

    /*root.appendChild(button);*/
    elements.put(name, button);
}

public static Element addDialog(String title,Element root) {

    System.out.println("dialog creata");
    Element dialog=doc.createElement("Dialog");
    dialog.setAttribute("id", "dialog");
    elements.put(title, dialog);
    return dialog;
}

public static void addLabel(String name,Element root){
    Element list = doc.createElement("DIV");

    Element label = doc.createElement("LABEL");

    label.setAttribute("id", name);
    label.setAttribute("class", "label");

    label.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(name));
    list.appendChild(label);
    /*root.appendChild(list);*/
    elements.put(name, list);
}


public static void addRadioButton(String name,Element root) {

    System.out.println("Radio button creato");
    Element button = doc.createElement("INPUT");
    button.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    button.setAttribute("name", "name");
    button.setAttribute("value", "value");
    button.setAttribute("id", name);
    button.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(name));
    button.setAttribute("onClick", buttonEvent);
   /* root.appendChild(button);*/
    elements.put(name, button);

}


public static void addTextField(int size, String title,Element root){
    Element list = doc.createElement("DIV");
    list.setAttribute("class", "areaditesto");
    Element label = doc.createElement("LABEL");
    Element textField = doc.createElement("INPUT");

    textField.setAttribute("type", "text");
    textField.setAttribute("placeholder", title);
    textField.setAttribute("id", title);
    textField.setAttribute("onkeyup", textEvent);

    label.appendChild(textField);
    list.appendChild(label);
    /*root.appendChild(list);*/
    elements.put(title, list);
}

public static void writePage(String fl) throws URISyntaxException{

    Iterator setsIterator = _partition.iterator();
    int id = 0;
    while(setsIterator.hasNext()){
        Set<String> set = (Set<String>) setsIterator.next();
        Element frame = addFrame("frame"+id);
        Iterator setIterator = set.iterator();

        while(setIterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) setIterator.next();
            Element element = elements.get(key);
            if(element != null){
                frame.appendChild(element);
            }
        }

        if(frame.hasChildNodes()){
            frames.put("frame"+id, frame);
            id++;
        }
    }


    Set<Entry<String, Element>> f = frames.entrySet();
    Iterator i = f.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Entry<String, Element> entry = (Entry<String, Element>) i.next();
        body.appendChild(entry.getValue());
    }

    addFooter();

    /*AGGIUNTA DEGLI SCRIPT*/
    addScript("js/hammer.min.js");
    addScript("js/index.js");
    addScript("js/test.js");
    addScript("js/cordova.js"); 
    addScript("js/phonegap.js"); 
    addScript("js/ionic.bundle.min.js");
    addScript("js/menu/menulaterale.js");
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;

    try {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fl);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**my class pDialog:**

```
public class pDialog extends pComponent {
Repository r= new  Repository();
ActionListener _actionListener;
ArrayList<pComponent>b= new ArrayList<pComponent>();


public pDialog(String title){
    _title= title;

}

public void addActionListener(ActionListener actionListener){
    this._actionListener= actionListener;
}


public void setSize(int x,int y){

}

public void add(pComponent component){
    component.setRoot(this);
    System.out.println(component.getName() + " add to dialog parent "+ this.getName());
    b.add(component);   
}

public void setRoot(pComponent root){
    super.setRoot(root);
}
public ArrayList<pComponent> getComponents(){
    return b;
}

public void create(){

    parserHTML.addDialog(_title, this.getRoot().getElement());
}
```

can you help me ? thank you.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MVCE]. As it stands, your code is way too long to be read by someone. Also, tell us what you have tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Hi Nathan, 
I can not do it anyway, to understand how the parser works, i tried to add a new method addDialog(). This method add a new dialog but but do not insert the components inside it, inserts them into main frame

Comment: There is a lot of code, and no explication with it. Try to shorten your request and clarify it: You want to take a `String` in java, parse it, and convert the elements in it to an `Element` in java? This is not clear at all in your question.

Comment: I need to convert the java user interface into html, to do this I rewritten the AWT library, so through the parser you see in the question each java component is transformed into html. I have difficulty creating the dialog, I can not integrate components.